# NHibernate one-to-many with discriminator

Tags: nhibernate

I have a table per class hierarchy mapped by discriminator. It works out great, but I'm not sure how to deal with the container class.

Scenario is pet contains cat, dog, and cat, dog are in one table. I found a hibernate solution as below, credit to chris [Polymorphic one-to-many](http://chriswongdevblog.blogspot.com/2009/10/polymorphic-one-to-many-relationships.html) . How can I do the same thing in NHibernate? Especially around @Where(clause="dtype='Dog'")

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
class Pet { ... }

@Entity
public class Cat extends Pet {}

@Entity
public class Dog extends Pet {}

@Entity
public class Owner {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    long id

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    List<Pet> pets

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Where(clause="dtype='Dog'")
    List<Dog> dogs

    @OneToMany
    @JoinColumn(name="owner_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)
    @Where(clause="dtype='Cat'")
    List<Cat> cats
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just filter the Pets collection when requested. In C# this would look like:

```
public List<Cat> Cats
{
    get { return Pets.OfType<Cat>().ToList(); }
}
```

Or return the Cats collection as `IEnumerable<Cat>` and leave off the `ToList()`.